# ARM visual studio 2010 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, cross-platform, arm

I would like to know if there is a plugin to help develop ARM target in visual studio 2010 or 2012.
thank's

Answer (score 0):

- Visual Studio 2008 includes an ARM compiler and can target Windows CE/Windows Mobile.
- Visual Studio 2010 does not include ARM compiler.
- Visual Studio 2012 includes an ARM compiler and can target Windows RT, and probably also Windows Phone 8 (I didn't try to compile for the latter).